# How can I load a property of a navigational property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I’m attempting to create a query  using eager loading of navigational properties.  Is there a way to load a property of a navigational property? I get a ‘sequence contains no element’ exception when I try the code below.

```
       var viewModel = new InstructorIndexData();
        viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors.Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
            .Include(i=>i.Assignments) 
             .Include(i => i.Students)
             .Include (i=>i.Enrollments )
            .Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))
            .OrderBy(i => i.LastName);

        viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(i => i.InstructorID == id).Single().Courses;
        viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseID == courseID).Where( e=>e.Enrollments.First().InstructorFullName == "Kim Abercrombie").Single().Enrollments;
```

However when I use:

```
            viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseID == courseID).Single().Enrollments;
```

it populates my viewModel.Enrollment property just fine.  Is there a way to access this type of complex property in a linq query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it.
     var selectTemp = viewModel.Courses.Where(x => x.CourseID == courseID).Single().Enrollments;

```
            var selectedTeacher = from t in selectTemp where t.InstructorFullName == teacher select t;


            viewModel.Enrollments = selectedTeacher;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to load a property of a navigational property?

Looks like you know how to eager load multiple levels already:

```
viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors.Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
        .Include(i=>i.Assignments) 
         .Include(i => i.Students)
         .Include (i=>i.Enrollments )
        .Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))
        .OrderBy(i => i.LastName);
```

This is where you are probably getting the exception (or possibly your other use of `.Single()`):

```
viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Courses
   .Where(x => x.CourseID == courseID)
   .Where( e=>e.Enrollments.First().InstructorFullName == "Kim Abercrombie")
   .Single().Enrollments;
```

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156472.aspx) for `.Single()`

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if
>   there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

Comment: I tried using First and   FirstOrDefault() but got the exception “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”.

Any ideas as to how to access the property during runtime?

Comment: @CloudyKooper, Neither of those will help you either your problem is that your query does not return any items. So `Single()`, `First()` will throw exception, `FirstOrDefault()` will return null and then throws null reference exception when you try and access properties on a non existent object.

Comment: When i use var selectedTeacher =from t in db.Enrollments where t.InstructorFullName =="Kim Abercrombie" select t;  It returns the name as i expect so Im guessing there is a conflict between a type string and type Enrollments.. I'm still fairly new to this so I'm not sure.

Comment: @CloudyKooper, try changing `e=>e.Enrollments.First().InstructorFullName == ...` to `e=>e.Enrollments.Any(x=>x.InstructorFullName == ...)`

Comment: Any() seems to return all records instead of only the ones that the string "Kim Abercrombie" is associated with.